# Slow TCP connection between local server/client

Tags: java, tcp

I'm trying to understand why I have latency spikes between a client and a server in a very simple setup. Below the code for both the client and the server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345); // Server socket is listening on port 12345
            System.out.println("Server started. Waiting for a client...");

            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // Server accepts the client connection
            System.out.println("Client connected.");
            clientSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            clientSocket.setSendBufferSize(16 * 1024);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            // Thread for receiving messages from the client
            Thread receiveThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        // Receiving timestamp from the client
                        String clientMessage = in.readLine();
                        long clientTimestamp = Long.parseLong(clientMessage);
                        long timeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() - clientTimestamp;
                        if (timeDifference > 1) {
                            System.out.println("Time difference: " + timeDifference + " milliseconds");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            receiveThread.start();

            // Thread for sending messages to the client
            Thread sendThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        // Sending current server timestamp to the client
                        long serverTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        out.println(serverTimestamp);
//                        out.flush();
                        Thread.sleep(2);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            sendThread.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the client

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345); // Connect to the server on localhost:12345
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
            socket.setSendBufferSize(16 * 1024);

            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            // Thread for receiving messages from the server
            Thread receiveThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        // Receiving timestamp from the server
                        String serverResponse = in.readLine();
                        long serverTimestamp = Long.parseLong(serverResponse);
                        long timeDifference = System.currentTimeMillis() - serverTimestamp;

                        if (timeDifference > 1) {
                            System.out.println("Time difference: " + timeDifference + " milliseconds");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            receiveThread.start();

            // Thread for sending messages to the server
            Thread sendThread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        // Sending current client timestamp to the server
                        long clientTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        out.println(clientTimestamp);
//                        out.flush();
                        Thread.sleep(2);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            sendThread.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to manually flush after each send but it doesn't improve anything.
I don't think that I should have spikes (2ms up to 10ms on the same machine - t3.large instance on AWS - 2vCPU/8GB RAM).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

After doing additional tests, the way to solve this is to open two connections: one to receive data and one to send data. TCP connection is full duplex but it depends on the underlying transport stack.

Comment: The underlying transport  stack is IP, probably over Ethernet, both full duplex. Maybe your NIC isn’t, but it’s most unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it still doesn't explain why it works using two sockets but not with a single one. I do have delays (more than 2ms on localhost and RecV-Q/SendV-Q that fill up)